# Laravel with PhpStorm, Method findOrFail not found

Tags: laravel, eloquent, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm v2021.2, have Laravel plugin (by Daniel Espendiller v0.15.4) installed and enabled, Laravel Query (by Ernestas Kvedaras v2.0.6) and I am also using `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` v2.10.0. I updated `composer.json` with this bit of code:

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
        "@php artisan ide-helper:meta",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
```

so it regenerates all meta and helpers and it successfully creates files `.phpstorm.meta.php` and `_ide_helper.php`.

All my models do extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Not directly, I also wrote a `BaseModel` with some of default properties, so it looks like this:

`BaseModel.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    //
}
```

`Client.php`

```
namespace App\Modules\Clients\Entities;

use App\Models\BaseModel;
...

class Client extends BaseModel
{
    //
}
```

But I am still seeing `Method 'findOrFail' not found in \App\Modules\Clients\Entities\Client`. What else can I do to make this notice go away?

Comment: You also ran php artisan ide-helper:models?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: It should've been solved by `ide-helper:models`. What are your `_ide_helper_models.php` contents? It should contain `class User extends \Eloquent {}`, and `_ide_helper.php` should have the `Eloquent::findOrFail()` definition.

Comment: Besides many more entries, these are all present. For now I resolved into writing docBlocks for each model and in BaseModel I added @mixin Eloquent. It works, but not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: You can contact us via Help | Contact Support, if you can submit a project copy with your report we'll probably be able to find out what's going on.

Comment: @KristjanO. have you tried adding `--write-mixin` flag to the `ide-helper:models` command? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#automatic-phpdocs-for-models